# Strange Behaviour of [SED] when put in shell script

Tags: linux, sed

when i am doing this

```
sed 1s/#text_to_be_replaced#/replacement_string/ filename
```

then the output is as expected but when i put it in a shell file
and do this

```
lineNumber=1
sed $lineNumbers/#text_to_be_replaced#/replacement_string/ filename
```

then it doesn't work as expected the `replacement_string` gets inserted one line above the `text_to_be_replaced`. Why is it happening ?

Comment: Replace `$lineNumbers`, which is empty, to  `${lineNumber}s`, which is `1s`, and tell if it gives the wanted result. I'd also highly recommend to put a command after `sed` into quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
sed "${lineNumber}s/text_to_be_replaced/replacement_string/" filename
```